# Google Code Jam 2014 Round A APAC Test - C Addition

Tags: testing

Please read the problem here - https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=3214486#s=p2

I am unable to get my solution accepted. So, I downloaded a correct solution and compared their output for the input to mine. Please see the following test case and help me understand why my output is wrong -

**Input**

```
1
10
b+b=156820
f+f=-189258
c+e=58886
e+g=31772
e+g=31772
b+b=156820
c+e=58886
g+e=31772
b+b=156820
e+c=58886
10
g+e
c+g
f+b
d+g
e+g
c+e
g+e
c+e
b+b
g+e
```

**Correct Output**

```
Case #1:
g+e=31772
e+g=31772
c+e=58886
g+e=31772
c+e=58886
b+b=156820
g+e=31772
```

**My Incorrect Output**

```
Case #1:
g+e=31772
f+b=-16219
e+g=31772
c+e=58886
g+e=31772
c+e=58886
b+b=156820
g+e=31772
```

As you can see, the correct output doesn't include ans answer for f+b. Could someone please explain why? I thought that the since the value of f can be calculated from f+f=-189258 and the value of b from b+b=156820, the value of f+b should be easily calculable.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is here you are not solving for f and b. You are adding and subtracting equations to get possible equations in the latter checkable ones. No combination of known equations will give you f+b that's why it's not there. The computer cannot solve for variables but can solve combinations of equations apparently.

Comment: Is there any line in the problem statement which confirms this or from which I can infer what you wrote in your answer?

Comment: Towards the beginning "Bob wants to find out answers to questions like a+b..." and the output tell me that's what's happening